# How can i optimize the speed of my statistic generations - multipule Eloquent models involved?

Tags: laravel

We developed a portal where our customer and their employees can track their sales, worktimes, etc. Inside these the managers can define their own statistics by creating a new statistic and select the needed products to monitor.

In the statistic section they can get a table of all employees (150) for their selected statistics.

To be a bit more specific: We have a SaleItem Model. In this sale_item the product_id is referenced. (Product Model)

We have a Statistic Model. Within this Model we have a relation to many StatisticProduct Models. (they belong to the Statistic)

Our Models:

```php
class SaleItem extends Model 
{

   /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

class Statistic extends Model
{

/**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function statistic_products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(StatisticProduct::class);
    }

}

class StatisticProduct extends Model
{

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function statistic()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Statistic::class);
    }

}
```

Inside of our Controller:

```php
public function showAllUserStats(Request $request)
{

    $start = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$request->get('start'));
    $end = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$request->get('end'));

    $stats = Statistic::where('active',1)
            ->select(
                'statistics.name',
                'statistics.id as statistic_id'
            )          
            ->get();
    $users = User::where('active', '=', 1)->get();

    foreach ($stat as $skey => $s) {          

                if (!Cache::has('products_statistic_'.$s->statistic_id))
                    $stat[$skey]->s_products = Cache::rememberForever('products_statistic_'.$s->statistic_id, function() use($s){
                        return StatisticProduct::where('statistic_id', '=', $s->statistic_id)
                            ->pluck('product_sku')
                            ->toArray();
                    });
                else $stat[$skey]->s_products = Cache::get('products_statistic_'.$s->statistic_id);
}

    foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
                $users[$key]->commission = SaleItem::whereBetween('created_at', [$start,$end])                    ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
                    ->sum('commission');
                $users[$key]->commission_base = SaleItem::whereBetween('created_at', [$start,$end])
                    ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
                    ->sum('commission_base');
                $users[$key]->works = Work::whereBetween('day', [$start,$end])
                    ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
                    ->sum('hours');
                foreach ($stat as $skey => $s) {
                    $sales = SaleItem::where('user_id','=',$user->id)
                        ->whereBetween('created_at',[$start,$end])
                        ->whereIn('sku',$s->s_products)
                        ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(user_id) as count'))
                        ->get();
                    $salesWithCategory =  SaleItem::where('user_id', $user->id)
                        ->whereBetween('sale_items.created_at', [$start,$end])
                        //->join('sale_items', 'sale_items.sale_id', '=', 'sales.id')
                        ->join('products','sale_items.product_id','=','products.id')
                        ->join('product_categories','products.product_category_id','=','product_categories.id')
                        ->whereIn('sale_items.sku', $s->s_products)
                        ->groupBy('product_category_id')
                        ->select([DB::raw('COUNT(sale_items.id) as sum'),DB::raw('product_categories.name as category_name')])
                        ->get();
                    //winback
                    if($s->statistic_id == 48)
                        $sales[0]->count += Sale::whereBetween('created_at',[$start,$end])->where('winback','=',1)->where('user_id','=',$user->id)->count();
                    $stat[$skey]->count = $sales[0]->count;
                    $stat[$skey]->salesWithCategory = $salesWithCategory;
                }
                $users[$key]->sales = $stat->toArray();

}

    return view('statistics.users',['stats' => $users]);

}
```

The view:

```php
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-responsive dataTable" id="usersTable">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Umsatz</th>                                   
                                    <th>Stunden</th>
                                    @foreach($stats[0]->sales as $sale)
                                        <th>{{ $sale['name'] }}</th>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                @foreach($stats as $user)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ $user->name }}, {{ $user->first_name }} / {{ $user->shop->shortname }}, {{ $user->shop->micro_region }} / {{ $user->role[0]->display_name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $user->commission }} €</td>                                       
                                        <td>{{ round($user->works,2) }}h</td>
                                        @foreach($user->sales as $sale)
                                            <td><span data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="<table>@foreach($sale['salesWithCategory'] as $category)<tr><td>{{ $category->sum }}</td><td>{{ $category->category_name }}</td></tr> @endforeach </table>">{{  $sale['count'] }}</span></td>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Everything i working as expected - but if a manager for example select 10 different statistics the stat generation is quite slow. Any help on optimizing this is appreciated.

I already tried eager loading the statistic_products - that doesn't help much as i'm caching the products at the moment and only fetching them if the statistic has changed...

Comment: You should organise your code in a way where no query execution inside a loop. I see you have 7 queries in loop. & so let's say you're loop size is 10 then your query will be executed 70 times which for sure make execution slow.

Comment: I know - but u don't see an option not to do it. That's why I'm asking...
I'm looping through the users and then through the stats - each time. On 150 users and 10 stats that is more than 1500 queries - i know.... Maybe i could group it (the stats - groupBy user_id) and the looping and check if the user_id is same....

Comment: Sometimes it helps just to describe a problem, think about it and rewrite your class ;)
I'm using group now and looping through it.  I was able to reduce my workload from 1800 queries to 17 queries and the memory consumption from 80MB to 9.8 MB. Thank you anyway @Vishal.

Comment: glad to know you find your way. all the best!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps just to describe a problem, think about it and rewrite your class ;) I'm using group now and looping through it. I was able to reduce my workload from 1800 queries to 17 queries and the memory consumption from 80MB to 9.8 MB